# Creating a smarter Webpack autoloader for React components (nested in their directories)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, naming, directory-structure

I could really do with a webpack guru to help explain if this is possible.

Here's my directory listing:

```
components/
   Editor/
      Editor.jsx
      style.module.scss
   UIListing/
      UIListing.jsx
      style.module.scss
```

In addition to a webpack alias to resolve within the components directory:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      ['~']: `${path}/components/`
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
```

So when I currently import `Editor`:

```
import Editor from '~/Editor/Editor
```

This is fine for me. But, is there any way (without moving the components out of their directory that I can resolve it this way instead?

```
import Editor from '~/Editor
```

Comment: I should add I have checked https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/ for documentation but I am struggling to find a solution here on how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

Figured a solution:

```
containers/
   Editor.jsx

components/
   Editor/
      Editor.jsx
      style.module.scss
   UIListing/
      UIListing.jsx
      style.module.scss
```

Editor.jsx:

```
import Editor from '../components/Editor/Editor'
export default Editor
```

webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      ['~']: `${path}/containers/`
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
```

Unfortunately it does require some extra work, but in my case this proves useful as I have a boilerplate UI kit which needs to be easy to get coding from the get go.

```
import Editor from '~/Editor'
```